# How to remove certain word from filename store as variable , not rename

Tags: batch-file

I am running this batch script to loop through the files in the folder and retrieving the filename and copying to a new folder.  Problem is I want to know how to remove the word "_UB04" from any file that contains "_UB04" in the filename only.

```
SET "word=_test"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b') do 
echo F| XCOPY %%f C:\test\%%~nf\%%f
pause
```

for example the folder which the batch is run on contains customer.xslx and customer_test.xlsx
THE INPUT IS:

```
C:\Desktop\incoming\customer.xslx
C:\Desktop\incoming\customer_test.xslx
```

THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
C:\test\customer\customer.xslx
C:\test\customer\customer_test.xslx
```

It moves the customer.xslx into the right folder, but for the customer_test.xslx it creates a new folder, when I want it to go into the C:\Desktop\incoming... folder.

Comment: Perhaps you should show also the INPUT that you expect to lead to the said OUTPUT...

Comment: It is really unclear what you want. `copy C:\Desktop\incoming\*.xslx C:\test\customer` is the only command needed to get from INPUT to OUTPUT according to your question if target folder already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have understood the task and explain it with my own words.

There is the input folder `C:\Desktop\incoming` with following files:

- **C:\Desktop\incoming**

  - customer 1.xlsx
  - customer 1_UB04.xlsx
  - Customer2.xlsx
  - Customer2_UB04.xlsx
  - Another Customer.xlsx

Those files should be copied to directories depending on customer name which is the file name. But files with `_UB04` after customer name in file name should be copied into the same directory as the file with same customer name not having `_UB04` appended.

The output directory structure should be:

- **C:\test\customer 1**

  - customer 1.xlsx
  - customer 1_UB04.xlsx
- **C:\test\Customer 2**

  - Customer2.xlsx
  - Customer2_UB04.xlsx
- **C:\test\Another Customer**

  - Another Customer.xlsx

This task can be done with following commented batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define input and output folder.

set "InputFolder=C:\Desktop\incoming"
set "OutputFolder=C:\test"

rem Copy each file in input folder to a subfolder in output folder
rem according to file name with _UB04 removed from file name.

for %%I in ("%InputFolder%\*") do (

    rem Assign just name of current file without path and
    rem without file extension to an environment variable.

    set "FileName=%%~nI"

    rem Use string substitution to remove from file name "_UB04" in
    rem any case to get the name of the subfolder in output folder.

    set "FolderName=!FileName:_UB04=!"

    rem Create the subfolder if not already existing from a previous copy.

    if not exist "%OutputFolder%\!FolderName!" md "%OutputFolder%\!FolderName!"

    rem Copy the current file to appropriate subfolder in output folder.

    copy /F "%InputFolder%\%%~nxI" "%OutputFolder%\!FolderName!"
)

endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working after testing and debugging.  Here is the final code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%j in ( "%%~nxf" ) do (
    for /f "tokens=2* delims=_.xslx" %%k in ( "%%~nxf" ) do ( 
        IF "%%~xf" == ".xlsx" echo F| XCOPY %%f C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\%%j_%%k\%%f
    )
)
)
pause
```

Comment: Attention: `"delims="` means: every character of the string is a delimiter. Not the whole string!. `delims=_.xslx`  means `_` is a delimiter, `.` is a delimiter, `x` is a delimiter, `s` is a delimiter, `l` is a delimter. Probably not what you want.

Comment: I understand that... I neededed to extract the _.xlsx from the second part of the filename